# Subscript out of Range in Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I'm trying to program a permit tracking worksheet but get the subscript out of range error. I'm not really well versed in VBA. The workbook is Permit Tracking Log. The line that seems to be giving trouble is Line 4 Set ws = Worksheets("PermitTracker"). When I hover over the Set ws the message is "ws = Nothing. Hovering over the rest gives message Worksheets("PermitTracker")=. Here is the Code.

```
  Private Sub cmdAddPermit_Click()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("PermitTracker")

iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

Exit Sub
End

With ws
  .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.txtEntryDate.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.txtIssueDate.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.ComboBoxDiscipline.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.txtFirstFlrSqFt.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.txtSecondFlrSqFt.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.txtBmtDevSqFt.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 8).Value = Me.txtAttGarSqFt.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 9).Value = Me.txtDetGarSqFt.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 10).Value = Me.txtDeckSqFt.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 11).Value = Me.txtWoodBurner.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 12).Value = Me.txtCommercialConstCost.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 13).Value = Me.txtElectricalPermitFee.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 14).Value = Me.txtGasPermitFee.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 15).Value = Me.txtPlumbingPermitFee.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 16).Value = Me.txtMiscMinPermitFee.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 17).Value = Me.txtContractorOwner.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 18).Value = Me.txtProjectAddress.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 19).Value = Me.txtPermitClosedDate.Value
End With

Me.txtEntryDate.Value = ""
Me.txtIssueDate.Value = ""
Me.ComboBoxDiscipline.Value = ""
Me.txtFirstFlrSqFt.Value = ""
Me.txtSecondFlrSqFt.Value = ""
Me.txtBmtDevSqFt.Value = ""
Me.txtAttGarSqFt.Value = ""
Me.txtDetGarSqFt.Value = ""
Me.txtDeckSqFt.Value = ""
Me.txtWoodBurner.Value = ""
Me.txtCommercialConstCost.Value = ""
Me.txtElectricalPermitFee.Value = ""
Me.txtGasPermitFee.Value = ""
Me.txtPlumbingPermitFee.Value = ""
Me.txtMiscMinPermitFee.Value = ""
Me.txtContractorOwner.Value = ""
Me.txtProjectAddress.Value = ""
Me.txtPermitClosedDate.Value = ""
Me.txtEntryDate.SetFocus

End Sub

Private Sub CmdCloseForm_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, _
  CloseMode As Integer)
  If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
    Cancel = True
    MsgBox "Please use the Close Form button!"
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: if that line is the issue then there is a typo on the name of the sheet, "PermitTracker" does not equal a name of a sheet in the active workbook.

Comment: This error usually means that the specified worksheet name can not be found. Are you sure you have a worksheet named _PermitTracker_ in the currently active workbook? Didn't you possibly mistype something?

Comment: I checked that so many times. The sheet is named Permit Tracker. Thank you. Working now.

Comment: Those pesky little spaces.  Glad we could help.

Comment: Line 8 was End If but I got the error End If without block If. I have nested formulas in some of the fields. Would that cause this to happen?

Comment: End if is only used at the end of an If block, such as If x Then y End If.  You don't have an If block.  Your code is not going to get past the Exit Sub line as written as this will exit the procedure.  I think you either wanted some sort of If statement to determine when to exit or to remove both the Exit Sub and "End" lines.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out. And also which If was needed. Interpretation of the message was key.